# Resize UIImage is inverting the orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to resize the UIImage but when I do this, the UIImage is changing the orientation. The original image is in vertical but when I resize the image's orientation is horizontal

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image

    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is related to the use of `CGAffineTransformMake`. You could try the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.f);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works great! Accepted because was the first

Answer (score 0):

UIImage have a property imageOrientation, which rotate images when presenting.

CGImageRef is the original image data, so if you want to keep the rotated orientation, you should consider imageOrientation. or use UIImage's drawInRect instead

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:newRect];
ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```